# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @ ng2-translate.ts:2

Tags: javascript, import, typescript, angular, require

Getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @ ng2-translate.ts:2
```

It's the line where I import @anguar/http

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
```

Not sure why I would get any error here since I do include the http dependency in the project:

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.9",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "ng2-translate": "2.2.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.31",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Focus Anbud</title>
  <base href='/'> {{content-for 'head'}}
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Loading Spinner -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/whirly.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ionicons.min.css">

  <!-- Theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flag-icon.min.css">

</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
  <!--<div class="wrapper">-->
  <app>
    <div class="whirly-loader" style="margin-left: 50%; margin-top:20%">Loading...</div>
  </app>
  <!--</div>-->
  <!-- ./wrapper -->

  <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
  <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AdminLTE App -->
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

  <!-- polyfills for older browsers -->
  <script src="vendor/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

  <!-- default -->
  <script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate.js"></script>

  <script>
  System.baseURL = '.';
    System.import('system-config.js').then(function() {
      System.import('main');
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you add systemJS in a script tag?

Comment: @Dinistro, it is not in the index file with a script tag, should it? added my index.html so you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

It should be:

```
  <script src="vendor/ng2-translate/bundles/ng2-translate.js"></script>
```

Not:

```
  <script src="vendor/ng2-translate/ng2-translate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found the issue: You import systemJs after your app and because of this, `require()` is not present at the moment it is used the first time. To fix this, you can move your import of the app.js under the systemjs:

```
<!-- default -->
<script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Additionally, you need to configure ng2-translate in your systemJs config and remove the script tag:

```
System.config({
    map: {
      'ng2-translate': 'node_modules/ng2-translate'
    },
});
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference unfortunately, and it's the ng2-translate.js file that gives the error, not app.js

Comment: @ganjan Do you compile to `CommonJS` (can be found in the tsconfig.json file)?